# How to draw a road in OSM Map?

Tags: maps, openstreetmap

This may sound ridiculous, but I need help.

I would like to draw a road which already present in **OSM map**. The data can be captured using export option from the same OpenStreetMap site. The exported data is in **.OSM** file (kind of XML thingy). Now the problem is if I like to draw a road based upon the WAY node of OSM Data. How it can be achieved ?

That Way node contains **RefId** and other way points so that it will be usefull in tracking the road.

Is there a way to achieve using **API** (or) any other option like **OpenLayers** ?

Comment: So you already know the way or node IDs you want to draw the route along? Or do you know just the geographic positions? In the latter case you could just use a router.

Comment: I got the Way and Node Id from .osm file which I exported. Now i would like to draw the road by the respective Id's.

Comment: That's a rather unusual approach. However you can obtain the full way geometry either via [OSM API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) or (usually preferred) [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).